# After insert trigger in postgres not working

Tags: postgresql, triggers

i am creating a trigger that is supposed to be fired every time a new device is added in to the device table. Since the id in the table is auto incrementing i have set is so that the trigger is fired after the insert. The insertion works but the trigger is not being fired or atleast i am not seeing the data in the table that is supposed to receive the information.

the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function insertstagingdevice() returns trigger as $device$

DECLARE
    begin
           INSERT INTO postgres.staging_import_remote_access.device(device_id,
                                                                     name, eui,
             
                                                                     location)
            VALUES(new.id,
                new.name,
                new.eui,
                new.location);
            RETURN NEW;
    END
$device$ language plpgsql;
```

The trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertionIntoDevice
    after INSERT
    ON postgres.public.device
    FOR EACH row
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertstagingdevice();
```

Is there something i am overseeing ?

Comment: Tried with a before trigger, i got an error bacause it couldn't  get the device id. i am just confused to why it's not reacting.

Comment: I have similar issue with partitioned table on 11.x postgresql. Just in case: a) `device` is a normal table? b) what is postgresql version?

Comment: The device is a normal table. 12.5

Comment: Can you check: a)  `RETURN NULL` instead of `RETURN NEW` in trigger function, b) `CREATE TRIGGER  AFTER INSERT ON public.device` (omit `postgres` from name) ?

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. there was an error elswehere. Thanks for your help